# Reference for homology of real projective space in a field.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I need a reference in a book for the computation of the homology of real projective space with coefficients in an arbitrary field.

I do know how to do the computation, and I also found an online reference (https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Homology_of_real_projective_space), but I just need a printed citation.

I can't seem to find it in several books I have here (Hatcher, May, Rotman).

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use the Universal Coefficient Theorem?

Comment: Think of projective space as CW-complex https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/CW_structure_of_real_projective_space

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown and Andrea, thanks for the suggestions, but I am writing an introductory level paper and I don't have room to develop cellular homology or universal coefficients, I just need this specific result about $RP^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Example 2.50 in [Hatcher](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html).